# Getting 'has no attribute' error using __import__

Tags: python

I've run across a strange issue, and I have not found any similar issues in my searches; which probably means the issue is plainly obvious and I am just not seeing it.
I have a class module called modulefile.py, in a folder called modulefolder.  Here is modulefile.py:

```
class moduleclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameter = 5
```

Now, in my test1.py file I do this:

```
from modulefolder.modulefile import moduleclass
myobj = moduleclass()
print myobj.parameter
```

And this works great - it prints the value 5 as expected.

Now, my problem is that in my application I won't know modulefolder, modulefile and moduleclass until runtime.  They will be provided to me in strings.  So I tried this, this is test2.py:

```
module = __import__("modulefolder.modulefile", fromlist=["moduleclass"])
myobj = getattr(module, "moduleclass")
print myobj.parameter
```

And this doesn't work, I get an error `AttributeError: type object 'moduleclass' has no attribute 'parameter'`.

So, this is what is baffling me.  In both test1.py and test2.py I changed the print statment to `print dir(myobj)` instead, and I get this:

For test1.py:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'parameter']
```

For test2.py

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

So, clearly, the second import method is missing my 'parameter' attribute.  The problem is, I don't know why.

Why does this method of dynamic import affect the way the instantiated object works?  And what can I do to fix it?

I've searched high-and-low looking for answers, so it's probably something straightforward that I've overlooked, or just don't fully understand.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the [`importlib` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) instead?

Comment: `myobj = getattr(module, "moduleclass")` returns the class, not an instance. try: `myobj = getattr(module, "moduleclass")()`

Comment: @MP - you see, I was having the same problem with importlib.  This should fix that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't instantiate your class in `test2.py`:

```
myobj = getattr(module, "moduleclass")()
```

Comment: Hah!  You see, I KNEW it would be something simple!